# remove duplicates command prompt on mac

Tags: osx-lion, regex, macbook-pro, duplicate, deduplication

I have looked for various free software to remove duplicate on my mac but could not find a good one. I have finally settled on command prompt to delete duplicate files but I can't get it to work either. May be I am missing something. I am familiar with command prompt but am not an expert on mac terminal esp find and grep. Can you someone provide a terminal command that will show duplicate files and will remove duplicates? I want it working on mac lion os x, otherwise I can find plenty online which does not work. A step by step tutorial will be helpful.

I have tried [1](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/10039/find-duplicate-files-based-on-md5-hash-for-mac-os-x) and [2](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20010828211333805) and many others. None of them work. Throws some kind of errors.

```
find . -size 20 \! -type d -exec cksum {} \; | sort | tee /tmp/f.tmp | 
cut -f 1,2 -d ' ' | uniq -d | grep -hif - /tmp/f.tmp > dup.txt
```

Comment: The md5 solution looks rather nice. Which *all sorts of errors* did you get ? What is the output if you run part of the command (e.g. run only `find /path/to/search/ -size 20 -type f -exec md5 '{}' ';'` on a test folder. Does that part work. If you add the next stage, does it error. Etc etc.

Comment: @Hennes I tried what you adviced. If I run the command in fragments, it runs fine. But the last part gives an error `grep -hif - /tmp/f.tmp > dup.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```
brew install fdupes
fdupes -rn .
```

- `-r` is recursive, `-n` ignores empty files
- Add `-dN` to delete all files except the first file

`find . -type f ! -empty -exec md5 -r {} \+ | awk '++a[$1]!=1' | cut -d' ' -f2- | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm`

- The md5 sum of empty files is the same
- `md5 -r` (reverse) prints the checksum and filename in an easier to parse format
- `++a[$1]!=1` prints all except the first line where the first column is duplicated

Related questions:

- [Removing duplicate files, keeping only the newest file](https://superuser.com/questions/504865/removing-duplicate-files-keeping-only-the-newest-file)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283021/identify-duplicates-and-delete
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26477/how-to-delete-duplicates-of-files-in-directory-and-subdirs
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71705/remove-duplicate-files
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34366/is-there-a-way-of-deleting-duplicates-more-refined-than-fdupes-rdn