# Remove duplicate files within specific directories, keeping them in another with Bash

Tags: bash, deduplication

I've seen a few questions on here regarding removing duplicate files in various circumstances but I can't find anything along the lines of what I'm trying to accomplish.

The closest I came was seeing the answer here [Removing duplicate files, keeping only the newest file](https://superuser.com/questions/504865/removing-duplicate-files-keeping-only-the-newest-fileanswer) but the I've that I've tried to modify but get a bad substitution error on the line

```
f=(${(f)files})
```

probably due to me running a bash shell and not a zsh one.

I have a multiple directories based on dates. Within each one are a number of subdirectories and files. Some of these files are duplicated and they may be in the same subdirectory or a different one.

eg

```
backup
  /2022-09-01
    /photos 
      image_a.jpg
      image_b.jpg
      image_c.jpg

backup
  /2022-09-02
    /photos 
      /album
        image_a.jpg
      image_b.jpg
      image_c.jpg
      image_d.jpg

backup
  /2022-09-03
    /photos 
      /album
        image_a.jpg
      image_b.jpg
      image_d.jpg
```

What I'd like to do is remove the duplicate files except for the one in the most recent directory.

So in the example above, after the script runs this would be left

```
backup
  /2022-09-01
    /photos 

backup
  /2022-09-02
    /photos 
      /album
      image_c.jpg

backup
  /2022-09-03
    /photos 
      /album
        image_a.jpg
      image_b.jpg
      image_d.jpg
```

I can find all the files, get the duplicates based on hash values etc but I cannot figure out how to remove the files within previous directories.

Comment: Is your goal to remove files? or to free some disk space? If the latter and if duplcate files are not already hardlinks, and if harlinking them is possible and acceptable, then `jdupes -L`. It won't matter which directory is most recent.

Comment: Ideally remove the files to save space so no hard links. Sticking with the example above the files could be from a camera or a drone or could be larger videos.  They go into folders, I review them then might organise them into folders based on event or topic etc., but wouldn't want to keep the previous copies if I've moved them into a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

[`jdupes`](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) can do it with its `-d` (`--delete`) option.

If all the direct subdirectories of `backup` are named according to the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD` then the default ordering by name should work, you just need to invert it (`-i`). This is because dates expressed as `YYYY-MM-DD` sort as you expect. The manual states the default ordering is "by filename", but my tests indicate it's rather "by pathname". I mean names of directory components do matter.

You can choose ordering by mtime: `-o time`, inverted (`-i`). This will be helpful if there are direct subdirectories of `backup` with names not following the pattern `YYYY-MM-DD`; but you need to be sure the content of the subdirectories was modified in the order you expect. If you created the subdirectories in this exact filesystem day by day then it should be so. If you copied them all at once from another filesystem then their mtimes may *or may not* be in the order you want.

I assume that ordering by name is fine in this case. At first you may try:

```
jdupes -rid backup
```

and be interactively asked which duplicate files you want to keep*. This will allow you to make sure the tool lists duplicates in the order you want. If the tool was told to keep just one duplicate automatically (without prompting you), it would keep the *first* one from each list.

Note this trial run may take a long time before the tool prompts you for the first time. I advise to run it though, just to review several sets of duplicates and to make sure the order of each list meets your expectations.

If it looks good then abort the trial run (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) and tell the tool to delete automatically (`-N`):

```
jdupes -ridN backup
```

Unfortunately, when being prompted during the trial run you cannot choose to "switch" to the automatic mode for the remaining sets (at least in `jdupes` 1.20.2 I tested). You have to abort and start over with `-N`, accepting the fact the effort of the trial run will be wasted.

In case you suspect that neither the default `-o name` nor the alternative `-o time` will give you the ordering you want, consider `-O`:

> `-O` `--param-order`
> sort output files in order of command line parameter sequence

so you can do e.g.:

```
jdupes -rdN backup/september backup/august backup/july
```

As the last resort you can omit `-N` and review each set interactively; or omit `-d` and parse the output with some custom tool or script.

Notes:

- `jdupes` finds duplicates by content. Names are irrelevant for this.
- `jdupes` will find duplicate files for you, regardless if they are in different `YYYY-MM-DD` subdirectories or in the same one. E.g. a file in `2022-09-03` plus its copy also in `2022-09-03` will still count as duplicates and `-dN` will remove all but one copy.

---

* Warning: `n` is the most destructive option, it means "keep *none*". `a` is the most safe option, it means "keep all". I'm mentioning this because many other tools ask "are you sure you want to delete?" or "overwrite?", or anything like "proceed with destruction?"; in those cases `n` meaning "no" is a safe option and you may be used to it. Well, not in `jdupes`.